# Caulking bathtub, is there supposed to be a hole?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, caulking

I am re-caulking the bath tub, and have a question. After I remove the caulk, is there supposed to be holes between the bathtub and the tile? My house is 9 yrs old, and I have never had the guest bathroom re-caulked. Or am I going too deep with trying to remove the caulk? Please see the images for more info. Thank you for your help!

[image]

This is a picture of the hole

Am I digging to deep? This is what I am getting below the caulk
[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], Srguti! The accepted way of saying "thank you" 'round these parts is to click the "up vote arrow" next to any answer that has helped you, and to click the check-mark next to the answer that has helped you _the most_. (You've only got one answer, so those are easy tasks!) If you'll spend a couple of minutes taking the [tour] and reading through the [help] you'll learn that and other little tips that will help you get the most out of this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it looks like you are getting out of the gap is the old grout and the caulk holding onto the grout. The grout when it was applied was the finish on the surface, but then the house dried out since it was new construction and caused some of the grout to loosen, so it was caulked at a later time. You are simply removing something that needs to be removed anyway. Clean it out very well, getting the old soap scum out of the gap so the new material will seal to the tub and wall and not to the soap scum. Let it dry thoroughly and caulk.

Comment: There should have been just caulk there in the first place and not grout due to the change in plane.+